# active storage - multiple services - direct upload not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I have two services defined in the `storage.yml`

```yaml
amazon:
  service: S3
  bucket: bucket1
  region: eu-central-1
  access_key_id: 321
  secret_access_key: 321

unsafe_files:
  service: S3
  bucket: unsafe-files
  region: eu-central-1
  access_key_id: 123
  secret_access_key: 123
```

I use the amazon service for some files and I wanted to use the `unsafe_files` service for other files so that I can put the into another `s3` bucket.

The models that use the `unsafe_files` service look like that (very simple):

```rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer_image
end
```

```rb
class CustomerImage < Image
  has_one_attached :file, service: Rails.configuration.settings[:unsafe_files_service]
end
```

`Rails.configuration.settings[:unsafe_files_service]` is just `unsafe_files`

in rails `application.rb` I'm setting

`config.active_storage.service = :amazon` so that by default it uses the `amazon` service defined in `storage.yml`

Now I want to direct upload the files using `form_with`, it's also quite simple:

```rb
<%= form_with model: [@customer, CustomerImage.new] do |form| %>
  <%=
    form.file_field :file,
                    accept: 'image/jpeg',
                    direct_upload: true,
                    multipart: true
  %>
  <%= form.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

now I know (or I think I know) how direct upload works under the hood in rails when using `active_storage`.
Some javascript listens for the on form submit event and first takes what's in the `file_field` and sends it to the `DirectUploadsController` which checks the image, generates the direct upload url and then we directly upload the file to the specified service. It's all here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6ecf1065da57360bdc9f1d85e2c2d9314dcb79e0/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/direct_uploads_controller.rb#L14

The service responds with the file key or id.
Afterwards the form submission continues and we save the id that we have received and that's how the relationship between the file.

But when we hit the `DirectUploadsController` and we create the blob it gets the default service_name (see: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6ecf1065da57360bdc9f1d85e2c2d9314dcb79e0/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L115)

So long story short, when using direct upload I can't choose a service I have to rely on rails default service.

Is there a workaround for that? Or maybe I have missed something?

Comment: If you want to call `create_before_direct_upload!` yourself (so that you can specify the `service_name`) then I think you must override `DirectUploadsController` somehow. You could write your own controller, or (advanced) try to re-open and patch `DirectUploadsController`. My app does the former.

Comment: I ended up re-opening `DirectUploadsController` (and also adding an option to the form `file_field` to pass a custom `direct_upload_url` It works nicely although I don't like that I had to mingle with internals soo much. I've checked `active_storage` gem and it seems that one would have to just add this feature cause with current implementation there is no workaround.

Comment: Glad you got it working. In lieu of other (better) answers, I'll convert my comment to an answer in hopes that makes it show up in searches better.

Comment: I've prepared a gist with a rough solution. In case  anyone wants to see how I've chosen to solve it. The exact code might be better but that's the approach I've taken and it seems working for us for now (we'll have to change it though cause I already see that fomr tag helpers are changing on the main branch) -> https://gist.github.com/beniutek/6681af441cf0eccd53bd6b220e3b95f6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `create_before_direct_upload!` yourself (so that you can specify the service_name) then I think you must override `DirectUploadsController` somehow. You could write your own controller, or (advanced) try to re-open and patch `DirectUploadsController`. My app does the former.

Update from the OP:

> I ended up re-opening DirectUploadsController (and also adding an option to the form file_field to pass a custom direct_upload_url It works nicely although I don't like that I had to mingle with internals soo much. I've checked active_storage gem and it seems that one would have to just add this feature cause with current implementation there is no workaround. – beniutek

Comment: currently, that is the way I've solved my issue so accepting the answer. Hopefully they will make it more flexible in the future

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue. This [PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38957) is for the issue, but it was reverted due to another topic.

My workaround for this issue is to override `blob_args` method in DirectUploadsController.

```rb
# app/overrides/direct_uploads_controller_override.rb
ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController.class_eval do
  alias_method :old_blob_args, :blob_args
  def blob_args
    old_blob_args.merge(service_name: params[:service])
  end
end
```

Load the override:

```rb
# config/application.rb
# ...
overrides = "#{Rails.root}/app/overrides"
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(overrides)

config.to_prepare do
  Dir.glob("#{overrides}/**/*_override.rb").each do |override|
    load override
  end
end
```

Instead of using the direct_upload option, manually set the data attribute `data-direct-upload-url`. For example:

```
<%= form.file_field :file, multipart: true, 
    "data-direct-upload-url" => rails_direct_uploads_url(service: "unsafe_files") %>
```

Comment: ha, nice trick with changing Rails autoloaders. Gonna remember that thing

Comment: Has this still not been fixed? This workaround is subject to attacks where the user can modify the service URL on the frontend